# synchronization doesn't working with counter?

Tags: java, json, csv, synchronization

I've programmed a converter which should convert from one file format (e.g. "csv") to another file format (e.g. "json") - everything works fine for small files.
For larger files the `int lineCounter` I am using in my `HashMap<Integer,String>` seems to "jump".
The first entry of the HashMap symbolizes the line number and the second entry of the HashMap symbolizes the data.

The source CSV looks like this (with about 3600 entries more):

```
_id,actor.displayName,actor.id,actor.objectType,generator.displayName,generator.id,generator.objectType,generator.url,object.displayName,object.id,object.objectType,provider.displayName,provider.id,provider.inquiryPhase,provider.objectType,provider.url,published,publishedClient,publishedServer,target.displayName,target.id,target.inquiryPhase,target.objectType,verb
,BasKolloeffel(UT),BasKolloeffel(UT)@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,person,LochemC,5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,ils,http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,LochemC,5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,ils,LochemC,5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,ils,ils,http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09,2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z,2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z,,Orientation,5485a7050ac61b1339a4da0e,Orientation,phase,access
```

The resulting JSON:

```
{
    "actor" : {
        "displayName" : "BasKolloeffel(UT)",
        "id" : "BasKolloeffel(UT)@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
        "objectType" : "person"
    },
    "generator" : {
        "displayName" : "LochemC",
        "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
        "objectType" : "ils",
        "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09"
    },
    "object" : {
        "displayName" : "LochemC",
        "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
        "objectType" : "ils"
    },
    "provider" : {
        "displayName" : "LochemC",
        "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
        "inquiryPhase" : "ils",
        "objectType" : "ils",
        "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09"
    },
        "published" : "2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z",
        "publishedClient" : "2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z",
    "target" : {
        "displayName" : "Orientation",
        "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da0e",
        "inquiryPhase" : "Orientation",
        "objectType" : "phase"
    },
    "verb" : "access"
}
```

After reading about 2000 more converted csv lines the JSON-structure gets messed up and starts looking like this:

```
{
},
"displayName" : "Vogel1",
"actor" : {
    "objectType" : "person"
    "id" : "Vogel1@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
"generator" : {
},
    "id" : "b0e88042-47ec-4bbb-e419-f997020956bc",
    "displayName" : "questioningscratchpad",
    "url" : "http://go-lab.gw.utwente.nl/experiments/2014-12-lochem/questioning_v1/tools/questioning/src/main/webapp/questioning_relative_density.xml"
    "objectType" : "application",
"object" : {
},
    "objectType" : "application"
    "id" : "b0e88042-47ec-4bbb-e419-f997020956bc",
"provider" : {
},
    "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09",
    "displayName" : "LochemC",
    "objectType" : "ils",
    "inquiryPhase" : "Conceptualisation",
},
    "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09"
    "publishedClient" : "2014-12-16T10:27:55.097Z",
    "published" : "2014-12-16T10:27:55.097Z",
    "displayName" : "unnamedquestions",
"target" : {
    "objectType" : "questions"
    "id" : "b911e97c-cb7f-4cec-ab99-440aecb029f5",
    "verb" : "access"
}
```

I've debugged the lineCounter (upper 50%, because before everything works normally) of the HashMap and I got the following when using `System.out.println(this.lineCounter);`:

```
65557
65591
65623
65657
65691
65725
65759
65790
65821
```

I'm expecting that the lineCounter will increment only by one (+1) for each token in the csv file and not by 30 or something like that. I thought this was a synchronization problem but even a synchronized block doesn't solve this problem.

I'm using this 2 methods to modify the HashMap:

```
public synchronized void putLineToMap(int lineCounter, String content) {
    this.lineMap.put(lineCounter, content);
    ++this.lineCounter;
}

public synchronized String replaceToken(String previousLine, String token, String replace) {
    --this.lineCounter;
    previousLine = this.readerSaver.replaceLast(previousLine, token, replace);
    return previousLine;
}
```

... for completeness I'll add the replaceLast method:

```
/*
 * @param   string      The String-Object to be changed.
 * @param   substring   The String-Object-Part to be replaced.
 * @param   replacement The String-Object which should replace the substring.
 * @return                  The (changed) String-Object.
 */
public String replaceLast(String string, String substring, String replacement) {
    int index = string.lastIndexOf(substring);
    if (index == -1) {
        return string;
    }
    return string.substring(0, index) + replacement
            + string.substring(index + substring.length());
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

** EDIT ** Here's the method I'm using to convert CSV to JSON.

```
/**
 * A utility function which gathers the data from a csv file to store it in
 * a for this fitting architecture. Afterwards the data will be processed
 * and stored in a valid JSON format.
 *
 * @param headerLineData The header of the CSV.
 * @param rowLineData ALL rows of the CSV with separator symbols between the
 * lines.
 * @param filepath The filepath where the JSON file should be saved to.
 * @param entries If a config file is used, one can find the header data to
 * parse in this hashset. If entries is null, the config file won't be used.
 */
public void createJSON(String headerLineData, String rowLineData, String filepath, TreeSet<String> entries) {

    try {
        String[] headerSeparatedData = headerLineData.split(",");

        //??? @flagLastValueLine
        boolean flagLastValueLine = false;
        //count the number of value rows.
        this.scan = new Scanner(rowLineData);
        while (this.scan.hasNext()) {
            this.scan.nextLine();
            ++this.numberLines;
        }

        //resetting the scanner
        this.scan = new Scanner(rowLineData);

        while (this.scan.hasNext()) {
            //Read first value row.
            String nextLine = this.scan.nextLine();
            //Split value-row.
            String[] rowData = nextLine.split(",");

            //For the first iteration - start tag
            if (this.whileLoopPassCounter == 0) {
                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "[");
            }

            //Debug
            if (this.lineCounter >= 65536) {
                System.out.println(this.lineCounter);
            }

            //Depth of current header node -> actor.id.ID -- Depth = 2
            int depthHeaderLevel = 0;

            //should keep in mind which key (without value-node) was last.
            Set<String> rememberKeyNode = new TreeSet<String>();

            //Iterate through all elements of the header row. If 4x "," = 5 Elements.
            for (int i = 0; i < headerSeparatedData.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "{");
                }

                //proof whether the config file is used. Only parse the header data in this hashset.
                if (entries != null) {
                    Iterator<String> it = entries.iterator();
                    int size = entries.size();
                    int newSize = 0;
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        String key = it.next();
                        if (!headerSeparatedData[i].contains(key)) {
                            ++newSize;
                        }
                    }
                    if (newSize == size) {
                        continue;
                    }

                }

                //is rowData empty? Then jump to the next condition.
                if (!rowData[i].equals("")) {
                    //get all single elements of the header and split them again. case: have sub-elements.
                    if (headerSeparatedData[i].contains(".")) {
                        String[] headerSeparatedLevelData = headerSeparatedData[i].split("\\.");
                        depthHeaderLevel = headerSeparatedLevelData.length;
                        //Iterate through the depth of Header Level
                        for (int k = 0; k < depthHeaderLevel; k++) {
                            //First case: headerlevel does NOT contain any direct value successor.
                            if (k <= depthHeaderLevel - 2 && !rememberKeyNode.contains(headerSeparatedLevelData[k])) {
                                //special case: does the last row contain a "," from the deepest level?
                                //if yes: set close-tag and begin a new block after this one.
                                int lines = 0;
                                synchronized (getClass()) {
                                    lines = this.lineCounter - 1;
                                }

                                String previousLine = this.lineMap.get(lines);
                                if (previousLine.contains(",") && this.flagSingleNode == false) {
                                    //decrement counter to edit the last line.
                                    previousLine = replaceToken(previousLine, ",", "");

                                    //edit last line and increment counter.
                                    putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, previousLine);
                                    //set close tag.
                                    putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "},");
                                    //if one goes in an other level than the first: remove flag / set false.
                                    flagLastValueLine = false;
                                    /**
                                     * GEPFUSCHT!
                                     */
                                    //case: last row contains "},"
                                    int lines2 = 0;
                                    synchronized (getClass()) {
                                        lines2 = this.lineCounter - 1;
                                    }
                                    String prevLine = this.lineMap.get(lines2);
                                    if (prevLine.contains("},") && k == 0) {
                                        //decrement counter to remove the last line.
                                        prevLine = replaceToken(prevLine, "},", "}");

                                        synchronized (getClass()) {
                                            this.lineMap.remove(this.lineCounter);
                                        }

                                        //notice the depth of the header level.
                                        for (int j = 0; j < depthHeaderLevel - 1; j++) {
                                            //if end node not reached, just put "}"
                                            if (j < depthHeaderLevel - 2) {
                                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "}");

                                            } //if end nose is reached, set close tag.
                                            else {
                                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "},");

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                rememberKeyNode.add(headerSeparatedLevelData[k]);
                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "\"" + headerSeparatedLevelData[k] + "\" : {");

                                this.flagSingleNode = false;
                            } //second case: headerlevel has a text node as his successor.
                            else if (!rememberKeyNode.contains(headerSeparatedLevelData[k])) {
                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "\"" + headerSeparatedLevelData[k] + "\" : " + "\"" + rowData[i] + "\",");

                                //if one is in the last level, flag should be set.
                                flagLastValueLine = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } //Header does not contain "." - Separation not necessary.
                    else {
                        //set the depthHeaderLevel to one, because there is only one element at the header.
                        depthHeaderLevel = 1;
                        if (!rememberKeyNode.contains(headerSeparatedData[i])) {
                            //if last line ends on ",", replace through "},"
                            int line = 0;
                            synchronized (getClass()) {
                                line = this.lineCounter - 1;
                            }
                            String prevLine = this.lineMap.get(line);
                            if (prevLine.contains(",") && !this.flagSingleNode) {
                                //decrement counter
                                prevLine = replaceToken(prevLine, ",", "");
                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, prevLine);
                                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "},");
                            }
                            putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "\"" + headerSeparatedData[i] + "\" : " + "\"" + rowData[i] + "\",");
                            //if one is in the last level, flag should be set.
                            flagLastValueLine = true;
                            rememberKeyNode.add(headerSeparatedData[i]);
                            this.flagSingleNode = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Three things done here:
                //1. if the last line contains a "," - remove it.
                //2. dynamically add the close tags of a BLOCK
                //3. reset the TreeSet
                if (i == headerSeparatedData.length - 1) {
                    int line = 0;
                    synchronized (getClass()) {
                        line = this.lineCounter - 1;
                    }
                    String prevLine = this.lineMap.get(line);
                    if (prevLine.contains(",")) {
                        //decrement counter to edit the last line with ",".
                        prevLine = replaceToken(prevLine, ",", "");
                        putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, prevLine);
                    }
                    //dynamically add the close tags of a BLOCK.
                    for (int l = 0; l < depthHeaderLevel; l++) {
                        if (l == depthHeaderLevel - 1) {
                            putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "},");
                        } else {
                            putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "}");
                        }

                    }
                    rememberKeyNode = new TreeSet<String>();
                }
            }
            this.whileLoopPassCounter++;

            if (this.whileLoopPassCounter == this.numberLines) {
                //remove last "," - if there is one.
                String prevLine = this.lineMap.get(this.lineCounter - 1);
                if (prevLine.contains(",")) {
                    //decrement counter to edit the last line.
                    prevLine = replaceToken(prevLine, ",", "");
                    putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, prevLine);
                }

                //close tag
                putLineToMap(this.lineCounter, "]");
            }
        }
        this.scan.close();
        saveResultToFile(this.lineMap, filepath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSVtoJSONStructureHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's way too much missing here. Where do you print the line number? What is `replaceToken` (inputs)? How do you use it? What is `readerSaver`?  How are you producing the JSON?

Comment: well I thought that the whole method would be TOO much. I'm posting the first part here in a few secs.

Comment: Hope that's enough @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: Ok to answer your questions here: I'm printing the lineNumber in method called `savedResultToFile`. Its inputs are the HashMap and the filename. A BufferedWriter writer the contents of the HashMap - line by line - into a file I create then. For the inputs of `replaceToken` see the method `replaceLast` of `readerSaver`. `readerSaver` is just a utility class with this method in it.

Comment: Why do you put random synchronized stuff in your code? You are mixing instance an class locks... Beside there's no threads involved (apparently) :S

Comment: How are you iterating?  Sounds like you fully process CSV -> JSON and store it in a Map<Integer, String> before writing it all out.  The `Map` interface does not require insertion order to be maintained, but specific implementations will maintain insertion order (i.e. `LinkedHashMap`)

Comment: @Diego: yeah, I know that this is silly but I thought that this would be the only way.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. I do process the csv file as a whole and convert it then. Is that wrong?

Comment: @X-Fate, that's fine, by the question still stands... how are you iterating on the map entries when you write the content back out?  You said you used a `HashMap`, but `HashMap` does not maintain insertion order.  It might happen to have the expected order for smaller data sets (as is your observation).  You could change to a `LinkedHashMap` to maintain your insertion order as expected

Comment: I'm gonna try something out and then come back. Gimme 5min. I think that's the solution. I just iterate over the entryset with `iterator.hasNext()` and don't get the data in the right order.

Comment: @Alex: You saved my project. I think that was a really stupid mistake! Would you mind to post this suggest as a real answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention using a `HashMap` to hold your `Map<Integer, String>` of line numbers + json entries, but `HashMap` does not maintain insertion order for entry iteration.

You can use a `LinkedHashMap` if you need to guarantee iteration order is the same as insertion order

Comment: Really big mistake to assume that a HashMap maintains the order. Thank you!

Comment: @X-Fate, no problem, you should make note that the `java.util.Map` interface has no order guarantees, but specific implementations do (the class-level Javadocs for `LinkedHashMap` outline this)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess.

If you program works with the first few data points, then I am guessing that rest of your data is not as clean. Maybe some of the lines have missing values for some of the columns in your csv file. I suggest that you do a check for each line that you read from the input file.

```
a. read one line from file
b. check if the line is in the expected format
     b.1 tokenized the line
     b.2 check if the number of tokens (length) is equal to the expected value, if not discard the line or do some thing to salvage the incomplete data point.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your proposal but I've proved the file. Nearly every line looks like the line I posted. Sure there are token which are missing in some cases but I've programmed a method which handles this case. And it cannot be that the first 2000 lines can be read properly and the last 1600 not.

Comment: If I were you, I am going to create a version that disregards data points that have missing values as a point of comparison. Then I will start my debugging from there.